# Set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in Google Cloud Flex App

Tags: asp.net, google-app-engine, debugging

I have an error in my asp.net core 2.1 app and would like to set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT setting to Development so that I can better debug.

There are samples for the appsettings.json file, but the ones I find specify IIS Express and I do not know what the App Engine uses.

Is there a way I can tell the instance to run with ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment here:
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following section to your app.yaml

```
env_variables:
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/reference/app-yaml